# Ember Data - What's the correct way to update relations after saving a record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data 1.0 beta.

I have a model defined like this:

```
App.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  practices: DS.hasMany('practice')
});
```

And when I fetch the the models  at api/artists, I get a collection and the payload for each artist includes a 'practices' attribute with an array of ids:

```
{
    "artists": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "An",
            "last_name": "Artist",
            "practices": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

So far so good. Ember magic occurs and I can access the "practices" property on an instance of "App.Artist" no problem.

Now, when I create an artist, the server returns with the following payload:

```
{
    "artist": {
        "id": 38,
        "first_name": "New",
        "last_name": "Artist",
        "practices": [
            4
        ]
    }
}
```

The model is updated with its new id. However, when I go to access "practices" I get the raw array values and not the related model instances I expect.

So, after creating a record with relationships, do I have to manually add the related objects back on to the instance? Or can I trigger the model to re-sync it's relations?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

**Update:**

It appears that the relations are lost because the model is not deserialized after the save operation is completed. The model can be pushed back onto the store, which will cause the data to be deserialized.

So, following from the code above, if I have an instance of App.Artist as `artist` then

```
artist.get('store').push('artist', artist.get('data'));
```

will cause relations to be available. However, I'm not still not sure if this is "correct."

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug and in the process of being fixed. Relations should be maintained automatically after performing a commit.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1214